# Creating a basic feed forward perceptron neural network for multi-class classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am new to neural networks and I want to create a feed forward neural network for mutli-class classification. I am allowed to use any code that is publicly available but not any MATLAB ToolBox as i don't have access to it (so no neural network toolbox). The goal is to classify the data into one of 10 classes. [Here is the data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/yeast/yeast.data), the class is defined by the three letter code in the last column.

When creating a neural network, do you simply define the amount of nodes and have each node in layer i connect to every single node in layer i+1? And then simply have them learn the weights themselves?

Also is there a source I could follow that has MATLAB code for creating a neural network with any amount of input, any number of nodes, and does multi-class classification that is feed forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general introduction to neural networks (it seems you still need to learn a bit what they are):
http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol4/cs11/report.html

Read this document which explain how feedforward networks with backpropagation work (maths are important):
http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html

Here you have one implementation in matlab with comments:
http://anoopacademia.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/back-propagation-algorithm-using-matlab/

Regarding your questions:

1) "When creating a neural network, do you simply define the amount of nodes and have each node in layer i connect to every single node in layer i+1?" Depend of the network you use. In simple fully-connected feedforward neural nets, yes.

2)"And then simply have them learn the weights themselves?" That's the general idea. You have some data of which you know their classes (supervised learning), which you will give to the neural network to learn the pattern, and after learning is finished you use this updated weights to classify new, unseen data.

Comment: Is that backpropogation just for updating the weights? Or does it train the entire neural network? How do i set number of nodes in the hidden layer and other parameters?

Comment: How do i apply this to a new sample?

Comment: Training a network is essentially finding the weights. the other free parameters may be determined by cross-validation. you apply the network to a new sample essentially in the same way that you train but you stop after you get the predicted output. please take a look at some introductory book regarding neural networks

Comment: I understand how to apply the neural network to a new sample, i was asking specifically about using the code you linked to. It seems to be labeled back propogation, which in my understanding is only the process of updating the weights, but not the process of training the entire network. Also the function doesn't return anything so how am i supposed to use it on a new sample?

Comment: if you read the above documents you should be able to understand. in any case, make as output V and W in the "BackPropAlgo" function, and then perform the steps of the "trainNeuralNet" until you get Output_of_OutputLayer which is the predicted output of the network

Comment: By "above document" do you mean the page with the code created by Anoop.V.S & Lekshmi B G? Or the other two documents which give a theoretical understanding of neural networks. I believe i already understand theoretically how neural networks work. I am just trying to understand how to modify the code by Anoop.V.S & Lekshmi B G so that i can make it my custom amount of nodes and train with my inputs/outputs.

Comment: I meant "above documents" like I said. All of them. I cannot do the work for you I can only guide you through it. If you do understand how they work you should have no problem to modify the code as it is practically done. Good luck.

Comment: I am curious, how do you use a neural network when the input is not a boolean 0 or 1? And how do you classify into multiply different classes? The documents don't really seem to cover that

Comment: @user3123955 you should accept an answer when it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that should help is to use [cross-entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) error instead of classification error or [mean-squared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) error (MSE) for such multi-class problem (especially for evaluation). [This](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/) is a nice article that explains the idea. I will quote its example here:

> Suppose we are predicting a person’s political party affiliation (democrat,
> republican, other) from independent data such as age, sex, annual
> income, and so on.
> ...
>
> Now suppose you have just three training data items. Your neural
> network uses softmax activation for the output neurons so that there
> are three output values that can be interpreted as probabilities. For
> example suppose the neural network’s computed outputs, and the target
> (aka desired) values are as follows:

```
computed       | targets              | correct?
-----------------------------------------------
0.3  0.3  0.4  | 0  0  1 (democrat)   | yes
0.3  0.4  0.3  | 0  1  0 (republican) | yes
0.1  0.2  0.7  | 1  0  0 (other)      | no
```

This neural network has classification error of 1/3 = 0.33. Notice that the NN just **barely** gets the first two training items correct and is way off on the third training item. Now see another output as below:

```
computed       | targets              | correct?
-----------------------------------------------
0.1  0.2  0.7  | 0  0  1 (democrat)   | yes
0.1  0.7  0.2  | 0  1  0 (republican) | yes
0.3  0.4  0.3  | 1  0  0 (other)      | no
```

This NN also has a classification error of 1/3 = 0.33. But this second NN is much better than the first because it nails the first two training items and just barely misses the third training item. **To summarize, classification error is a very crude measure of error.** See below for a comparison of the classification error and Average cross-entropy error in the two cases:

```
Neural Network | classification error   | Average cross-entropy error
--------------------------------------------------------------------
NN1            |        0.33            |     1.38
NN2            |        0.33            |     0.64
```

To use cross-entropy error in the training, you need to use a different cost function.
See details [here](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression#Cost_Function).

[image] where `m` is the number of training examples and `k` is the number of classes; `y` is the label; `x` is the feature vector; `\theta` is the weight parameter.

Comment: this is a good introduction to cross-entropy. Yet I think his problem is more general than that.